# import all strings from file in c

Tags: c, file, text, import

Is there a way to import all strings from a text file at once?
I want to import all prices from a text file, where the string is composed by the name of the product and the price itself in the same line. Example: "Wood 5\nIron 10\n".
My function is:

```
fp = fopen("prices.txt", "r");
fgets(chestplate, 80, (FILE*)fp);
fgets(helmet, 80, (FILE*)fp);
fclose(fp);
```

This makes the var chestplate "Wood 5" and the var helmet "Iron 10", is there a way to loop the function so I dont need to import one at a time?

Comment: Hint:  learn about `while` and the return value from `fgets`.  You are already pretty close.

Comment: Yes, C has looping constructs: `for`, `while`, and `do ... while`.

Comment: You will have to rethink that strategy as soon as you realize you cannot make up variable names for each of your lines. That takes a bit more than 'loop, just loop'.

Comment: How do you know the order of the lines in your text file? You will need to make a mapping of some kind that says "line 1 is the chestplate, line 2 is the helmet." Is that also in the text file, or defined by the order you wrote them out, or just a sequence you chose at random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would loop through all the lines in the file.

```
char string[80];
while (fgets(string, 80, fp)) {
    // Do something to string
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Continuing the example started by @Fjotten, here's some (untested, uncompiled) code that could read a single "price". You'll want to loop over all of them, and then store them in whatever data structure you need - probably some kind of object array.

```
#define ERROR_MSG(...) ... whatever you want ...
#define STREQUAL(a,b) (0 == stricmp(a,b))

typedef struct {
    int wood;
    int iron;
    int bronze;
    int diamond;
} PRICE;

PRICE * get_price(FILE * fp) {
    char line[80];
    int  line_no = 0;
    char units[80];
    int  qty;
    PRICE * price;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        // Skip over blank lines, comments?

        if (sscanf(line, " %s %d", units, &qty) != 2) {
            ERROR_MSG("sscanf error reading prices, at line %d", line_no);
            continue; // break? exit?
        }

        if ((price = calloc(1, sizeof(PRICE)) == NULL) {
            ERROR_MSG("calloc failure reading prices, at line %d", line_no);
            exit(1);
        }

        if (STREQUAL("wood", units)) {
           price->wood = qty;
        }
        else if (STREQUAL("iron", units)) {
            price->iron = qty;
        }
        // else if ...
        else {
            ERROR_MSG("Unrecognized currency '%s' reading prices, at line %d",
                units, line_no);
            continue;
        }
        return price;
    }
}

typedef enum {
    CHESTPLATE,
    HELMET,
    NUM_TREASURES
} TREASURE_TYPE;

typedef struct {
    TREASURE_TYPE tr_type;
    PRICE *       tr_base_price;
    const char *  tr_name;
} TREASURE;

TREASURE Treasures[NUM_TREASURES];

void get_treasures(prices_file) {
    if ((fp = fopen(prices_file, "r")) == NULL) {
        ERROR_MESSAGE("Unable to open treasure prices file '%s' for reading", prices_file);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (ttype = 0; ttype < NUM_TREASURES; ++ttype) {
        Treasures[ttype].tr_type = ttype;
        Treasures[ttype].tr_base_price = get_price(fp);
        Treasures[ttype].tr_name = "I got nothing!";
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```